# JQuery .html() print accurate html code

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

I have a text area that I am populating with `html` code for people to cut & paste from.  This textarea is "populated" using JQuery and .html(). with the "population" coming from a `<div>` elsewhere on the page example:

Div that "holds "population"

```
<div id="populationhold">this is the html to copy</div>
```

then the "magic of JQ" to "click" button and populate the textarea

```
$('#button').click(function(){ 
updatefunction();
});
```

and updatefunction is a bit like this:

```
function updatefunction(){
$('#textarea').html( $('#populationhold').val(); });
}
```

Now if I try to populate with something like this:

```
$('#textarea').html( 'this is the <br />html to copy');
```

The .html() will only print `<br>` NOT `<br />`.  I have tried (in my way escaping with `<br \/>` but that doesn't do it.  Suggestions please as I must "produce" clean XHTML code not just HTML4 code

The next bit is prob. just the same, but a bit more complex - hence the above to lead into this.

As a "user" of my site you will be able to add/delete bits from the code example:

```
<div id="populationhold">
<div class="codebit1">this is the <br />html to copy</div>
\n<br/>\
<div class="codebit2">this is more <br />html to copy</div>
</div>

$('#button').click(function(){ 
$('#textarea').html( $('#populationhold').val(); 
});
```

Populating the textarea is fine and works and so does "90%" of the delete. which is something like this:

```
$('#deletebutton').click(function(){     
$('.codebit1').remove(); 
// This removes .codebit1 from #populationhold and runs the update to ummm update the textarea with the update function 
// Note: remove() is OK in this case as #codebit1 is totally dynamically created
updatefunction();
});
```

The question here is OK I can remove/delete the bits that need deleted - hence the "90%" but how can I get rid of the "now orphan" `\n<br/>\n` that used to separate the 2 divs in #textarea.  OK I can do it without the `\n<br/>\n` but it makes the code to copy "untidy" on the eye that is why the `\n<br/>\n` is there - also the `\n<br/>\n` does ensure that when the code is actually copied the user gets a sensible layout.

Comment: Are you using correct doctype though?

Comment: @Timo I was just about to ask the same thing…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not correct I think.

A `<textarea>` is a multi line input object. So, you don't want to use the `$('#textarea').html()` function (I don't think it even exists for a `<textarea>`), but you want to use the `$('#textarea').val()` function to update it's contents.

If you do `$('#textarea').val( 'this is the <br />html to copy')`, you will get the correct result.

On the other hand, you do want to use `.html()` instead of `.val()` for the `$('#populationhold')` object, since you're retrieving it's value and it's children.

**About innerHTML and XHTML**

XHTML and innerHTML are no friends. They just don't work together. If you serve your document as xhtml/xml then you're getting in trouble. It doesn't make sense, innerHTML in XML.

```
<element>value
 <child>childvalue</child>
</element>
```

innerHTML is just a function that gets the element's value, then concatinates it's childrens's name and value... It's just some string manipulation.

**Semi solution**

Steve Tucker created a [innerXHTML](http://www.stevetucker.co.uk/page-innerxhtml.php) function. You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pYUD4/10/

There is, however, one thing you get `<br />` is translated to `<br></br>`, but however, as far as I'm concerned, that's valid XHTML. I'll try to write a function that does the job well, because it seems like there is no way to do it now. But that might take some time xD

Comment: @Timo - Durr html not val , thnks but even so it doesn't print <br/>

Comment: Hmm, yeah I was playing with it just now. It seems that the jQuery html function encodes it or so... Let me check it out xD

Comment: @Timo - this and above <!DOCTYPE html> <html dir="ltr" lang="en"> - "standard" HTML5

Comment: @Timo - nearly there, very ugly but does suit my purpose am sure it can be tidied up - ALOT ;) - var codeed = $("#populationhold").html(); var tested = codeed.replace(/">\n<br>/g,'"\/>\n<br />\n');var tested1 = tested.replace(/ect>\n<br>/g,'ect>\n<br />\n'); var tested2 = tested1.replace(/area>\n<br>/g,'area>\n<br />\n'); $('#textarea').text( tested2);